# Drop-in replacement for PHP-based image gallery "Gallery"?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, php, web-server, gallery

Does anybody know a good alternative to [**Gallery**](http://galleryproject.org/), as that [project is under hibernation](http://galleryproject.org/time-to-hibernate)?

It would be nice if there is/was an active project which has the same feature-set.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_Project):

> Gallery or Menalto Gallery is an open source project enabling
>   management and publication of digital photographs and other media
>   through a PHP-enabled web server.

As a drop-in replacement it would need to be able to run on -

a. Apache2.4.x - latest in debian is 2.4.23

nginx would also be ok but apache preferred.

b. MySQL 5.x - latest in debian is 5.6.30-1

Postgresql may also be possible but mysql preferred.

c. PHP version 7.0.x - latest in debian is 7.0.12-1

Essential feature-set it would have to have -

1. Photo manipulation includes automatic thumbnails, resizing, rotation, and flipping, among other things.
2. Albums can be organized hierarchically and individually controlled by administrators or privileged users
3. The code needs to be foss/open-source license which is used/compatible with Debian Main - See https://www.debian.org/legal/licenses/
4. The project should be a mature project having a few public installations to see and feel how it works.
5. Should be a public hosted repository either on github or their own personal repository. Bzr or/and mercurial also works.
6. There should be some history of accepting patches from third-parties.
7. Should be an active project.

While it may or may not be possible to have all the above points, if they are any projects closer to the points above, please share those with links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as an alternative i use [**Piwigo**](http://piwigo.org/):

- runs on Apache, Nginx or Lighttpd (Apache or Nginx recommended)
- needs MySQL 5 or greater or MariaDB equivalent
- needs PHP 5.2 or greater *(found no explicit statement about PHP 7.0)*

a overview of your desired features:

1. thumbnails, resizing, rotation, adding watermarks, etc. via ImageMagick
2. sorting via albums/folder and calendar (exif-metadata)
3. foss under GPLv2
4. is developed since 2002 and collected numerous [Showcases](http://piwigo.org/showcase/)
5. hosted on github: https://github.com/Piwigo/Piwigo
6. look at 5.
7. look at 5.

i want to add some points (from my point of view) worth mentioning:

- multilingual translated into 50+ languages
- capable of adding photos local via file-manager, ftp, web-form and some photo-managers
- supports auto-tagging or via web-interface
- access control with groups
- notifications via rss, e-mail, etc.
- ratings and comments
- and via hundreds of plugins the features can be extended (like playing videos, showing geo-tags,...)
- also the look can be changed via lots of themes

Comment: This answer is a confirmation of what I had found in previous Google searches.

Answer (score 1):

How dropin?  If you want the same theme, reuse of the same database tables, etc, then good luck.

Assuming that you are willing to reindex the master images, rebuild thumbnails, then there are several options.

In addition to Piwago:

- Coppermine http://coppermine-gallery.net/

Good webserver (Apache recommended);
PHP (4.2.0 or better; full PHP 7 support with cpg1.6.x);
MySQL (3.23.23 or better; 4.x recommended);
either GD or ImageMagick (any version);

- Zenphoto:  http://www.zenphoto.org

MySQL min 5+ 5.5.3 recommended
PHP 5.3 min, 7.x recommended

Both of these seem to have more granular user controls than Piwago.